# What is int*(*asex)[5];?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

Because I couldn't find any reading that explains anything more than `int(*p)[5];`
I decided to ask a question here, that may also be used as a reference in use of other users, because it is a bit confusing I think.
What the heck is `int*(*asex)[5];` ?

I am self-taught, but also I've never seen it explained in a variety of different courses AND I never used it in practice. Right now, I need a clear explanation of that, because I am creating a C code analyzer for my project. Even though it wasn't directly explained to me, I am used to the language semantics so here is what I *think* it means:

- `int(*a)[5];` Clearly a pointer to an array of 5 ints (pointer to `int[5]`)
- `int(**asex)[5];`  pointer to an array of 5 int pointers?
- `int(*arr[10])[10];` That should be an array of 10 pointers to `int[10]`
- `int*(*asex)[5];` What is that? pointer to a pointer to `int[5]` ?

What did I got wrong?
Additionally, I feel like the only real advantage of this is shown with pointer arithmetic, is that true?

Comment: Try: https://cdecl.org/

Comment: Gosh! I need to run off immediately, but that looked interesting in the brief moment that I checked it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a trick to read these definitions: the spiral method.

1. start from the identifier: the variable name for a variable definition, the type name for a typedef and the innermost `*` for an anonymous type such as a cast.
2. parse the suffix operators left to right (`[]` for arrays and `()` for functions), if you reach a `)`, skip to the next rule
3. then parse the prefix operators right to left, `*` for pointer to
4. when you reach a `(` skip back to step 2 for the parenthesized expression.
5. if you reach the final type stop.

Applying this to the examples:

- `int(*a)[5];` defines a pointer to arrays of 5 ints. Typically the type received by a function taking a matrix defined as `int mat[4][5]`;
- `int(**asex)[5];` defines a pointer to a pointer to arrays of 5 ints. The type of the address of the function argument defined above.
- `int(*arr[10])[10];` defines an array of 10 pointers to arrays of 10 ints. You could store 10 pointers to matrices with 10 columns and various numbers of rows.
- Finally `int*(*asex)[5];` defines a pointer to arrays of 5 pointers to int.

Here are the steps in detail for the last example:

In `int*(*asex)[5]`, start from `asex`, **`asex` is a**, look right, hit `)`, start again from `asex`, look left, `*` is pronounced **pointer to**, hit `(`, start again from the `)`, look right, `[5]` pronounced **array(s) of 5**, hit `;`, start again from `(`, look left, `*` pronounced **pointer(s) to**, `int`, pronounce the final type **`int`**.

Hence the phrase: *`asex` is a pointer to arrays of 5 pointers to `int`*.

Comment: Can you tell me what "start from the symbol" means?
Other than that, it sounds like the right way of parsing such a declaration and therefore is what I have to do.

Comment: @Edenia: I updated the answer with an explanation: *symbol* was not the proper term (I use it in compiler implementations, probably influenced by my lisp days in the early 80s). In `int*(*asex)[5]`, start from `asex`, **`asex` is**, look right, hit `)`, start again from `asex`, look left, `*` is pronounced **pointer to**, hit `(`, start again from the `)`, look right, `[5]` pronounced **array(s) of 5**, hit `;`, start again from `(`, look left, `*` pronounced **pointer(s) to**, `int`, pronounce the final type **`int`**. *`asex` is a pointer to arrays of 5 pointers to `int`*.

Comment: You should probably include this comment in the answer as I find it for quite natural and easy to understand :)